# Rails - Given Project > Permission. How to prevent Project from being created w/o at least 1 permission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
Project (id)
Permission (project_id, user_id)
```

When user's create a project, I want to ensure that a group can not be created without there being at least one permission (1 or more).

Is there a way to add this validates to the Project model?

**UPDATE**

**project controller**

```
@project = current_user.projects.new(:name => params[:project][:name])
@project.permissions.build(:user_id => current_user.id)

respond_to do |format|
  if @group.save
  ......
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that your Project model has_many permissions, in which case, you can do the following:

```
validates_presence_of :permissions
```

Comment: Update the question with the controller, is that being created correctly? Thanks!

Comment: Change it from build to create!.  Build doesn't save the permission, so the project isn't valid until that's been saved.  I'd also change it to: @project = current_user.projects.new(params[:project]) though.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that ut that error'ed with ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved (You cannot call create unless the parent is saved)